# Generated .ear.xml for Liberty in Eclipse is wrong

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, websphere-liberty

### Problematic plugin

I have an issue with the eclipse Liberty plugin which is available [here on the marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-liberty-developer-tools-beta). I linked the beta, but the behaviour with stable is exaclty the same.

### Maven ear project description

I have a maven project which consists of multiple maven modules. The ear module's pom.xml looks like this. By the way, the maven generated ear looks just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>myear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <name>my ear module</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
      <artifactId>myWARmodule</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <!-- EJBs are not to be included in the war. -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
          <artifactId>myEJBmodule</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
      <artifactId>myWARmodule</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
          <artifactId>myEJBmodule</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jar module -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
      <artifactId>myAdditionalJarModule</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EJB module -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
      <artifactId>myEJBmodule</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- API implementation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsr107.ri</groupId>
      <artifactId>cache-annotations-ri-cdi</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>myEarApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <version>7</version>
          <finalName>myEARApp</finalName>
          <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
          <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib</defaultJavaBundleDir>
          <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>

          <modules>
            <!-- Root level modules: WAR and EJBs. -->
            <webModule>
              <groupId>my.groupd</groupId>
              <artifactId>myWARmodule</artifactId>
            </webModule>

            <ejbModule>
              <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
              <artifactId>myEJBmodule</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>

            <jarModule>
              <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
              <artifactId>myAdditionalJarModule</artifactId>
              <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
            </jarModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

### Resulting ear

The resulting ear file is structured like this:

```
myEARApp.ear
- myWarApp.war
   -- (no libs in WEB-INF/lib)
- lib/
  -- (a lot of libs here due to skinny wars)
- myEJBmodule.jar
- myAdditionalJarModule.jar
```

### Properties - Maven assembly descriptor

When I click the ear project and look at "assembly descriptor", the assembly matches  the layout of the ear file, which correct.

So, this is fine.

### Creating a liberty server and adding the application

Now, when I add  in eclipse a server and want to run the ear file, I create a "websphere liberty profile server", version 17.0.0.2. I then add the ear module to the server, configure the application (i.e. application bindings etc.).

The server can run the project from workspace by generating a replacement `myEARApp.ear.xml` file in the server/apps folder. It has the structure of the ear file. Well, it should have. Since two weeks or so, the structure of the `myEARApp.ear.xml`-file is more like this:

```
myEARApp.ear
- myWarApp.war
   -- a lot of libs from the war module
   -- myEJBmodule.jar
   -- myAdditionalJarModule.jar
- lib/
  -- only a few extra jar modules referenced in ear/pom.xml
  -- missing: logback, ehcache, etc.
- myEJBmodule.jar
- myAdditionalJarModule.jar
- otherDependencyOfmyAdditionalJarModule.jar
```

The bad thing is that this obivously won't run due to duplicate beans available for injection and a lot classnotfoundexceptions.

### How to solve?

So, my question is: How does the eclipse liberty profile plugin generate it's .ear.xml-file? Why does it differ from the layout I configured in the pom.xml? Even without skinny wars and the import scope dependency, the generated myEARApp.ear.xml file for liberty won't change.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution.

I removed a lot of jboss plugins from eclipse, like JBoss developer tools, JBoss Hibernate, etc.

I just kept a few:

- CDI tools
- Java EE Batch Config Tools
- JMX Console
- M2E connector for Eclipse JDT Compiler
- Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT APT

Now it works just fine again. Who would have thought that? Also, it didn't appear in any log why the generation of the .ear.xml file for liberty was corrupted by JBoss Dev Studio or other plugins.

I hope this is useful to any other developers.

Comment: I had a problem with contextRoot, configured as "/" but Jboss insisted to publish on "/web". This solved my problem. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

WDT generates the myEARApp.ear.xml file based on the deployment assembly settings in the project properties. When the project is imported into the workspace, the Eclipse M2E plugin is supposed to interpret the pom.xml and translate the settings and setup the deployment assembly in the project properties based on the settings in the pom.xml file.

Can you check the Deployment Assembly page in the project properties of the EAR and Web modules to see if the module is being setup properly as you would expect?  The other thing that you can try is to export the EAR file (using the Export menu when you right click on the EAR project).  If the exported project does not have the structure that you expect, then the problem is caused by the Eclipse M2E plugin does not support skinnyWars properly as mentioned in the bugzilla on the earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks. It did work once with `skinnyWars`, though. I thought it was ibm-wdt then. I'll check the settings page you suggested. If it works, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi Elson, sadly the deployment descriptor shown in Eclispe looks just fine. It shows a lot of libraries in the ear's /lib-directory. Seems that the liberty plugin does not obey this assembly. Anything else I could check?

Comment: Just checked the option to export as ear file. This is also wrong, as the generated .ear.xml file. So it must be the eclipse M2E plugin. But I think the problem is not the skinny war part. I'll check my m2e config and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Eclipse M2E plugin doesn't support `skinnyWars`.  You can try the work around at the bottom of the bug report.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461613

Comment: If your read my last sentence: It doesn't even work without skinnies. No luck here.